# Physics functions with different resolutions(Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have my scripts:

1. `Collider2D[] hitColliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(vector 2 pos, float radius);`

I need to get all colliders from point(pos) with radius half of Screen.width with different screen resolution. How can I give these parameters (pos and radius) to this function?

2. `playerObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (new Vector2 (direction.x * powerMultipl,direction.y * powerMultipl), ForceMode2D.Impulse);`

The same thing! I want to scale my force depending on screen resolution!

All I need is my game to be played in the same way on devices with different screen resolution! Thnx for helping me!

Comment: It's *incredibly* difficult to make games work perfectly and properly on all screen sizes and aspect ratios.  This is why game development costs millions and game companies have 100s and 100s of engineers.  You will spend literally months of your life working on this if (for some reason) you want to do it.  Really I would just forget about it.  Just enjoy it as a hobby.  Work on fun animations and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Always be careful about screen space and world space the Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll() function takes all the parameter with respect to world space (Cartesian coordinate) so first convert screen space to world space using

```
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(ScreenCoordinate) // returns a vector3
```

you also have to convert Screen.width into world units , check below

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/736142/what-is-good-practice-to-set-pixels-to-units-to-an.html